# Vehicular Dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

> Consider an open differential connected to two wheels on each side. The wheels are flat discs and are 1400 mm apart. This car is making a turn of radius 7 m at a constant angular velocity of 30 degrees / sec. The gear ratio of side gear to spider gear is 1.75. Assume the differential to have 2 spider gears.
>
> Find the angular velocities of all the gears inside the open differential.

I feel that the radius of the ring gear must be given to solve it but my professor says it is not needed. Can someone please help me solve this question?

Comment: To ask a homework related question, the practice is to present your attempted solution and ask for help on a certain detail or physical concept, not an open ended request for help

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the equations are

$$\omega_{{3}}=\frac 12\,I_{{D}} \left( \omega_{{1}}+\omega_{{2}} \right)\\
\omega_{{4}}=I_{{G}}\omega_{{3}}\\
\omega\,R=\omega_{{1}}r\\
\omega\, \left( R+d \right) =\omega_{{2}}r
$$

thus you obtained 4 equations for the 4 unknows $~\omega_i~,i=1..4$

Comment: What is Id and Ig?

Comment: $I_G$ is the gearbox ratio and $I_D$ is the rear axle drive ratio